# PyQt5 UI Freezes ADB & SCRCPY are also being used when freezing

Tags: python, pyqt5, adb

I am trying to create a program using PyQt5, ADB, scrcpy, and python. When I click on connect, which starts a scrcpy server and mirrors the android device on the screen, my UI freezes until I close my scrcpy session/server. I will share both .py file codes that are used to make this work and look.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import os
import sys
from ADBee import *
from twt_start import *

devs = devices()
log_window = []
# GET LIST OF CONNECTED SERIAL NUMBERS
os.chdir('resources/ui/')
class TB_Main_Window(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(TB_Main_Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)
        self.find_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.find_devices(devs))
        self.connect_button.clicked.connect(self.connect_to_device)
        self.disconnect_button.clicked.connect(self.disconnect_from_device)
        
        self.connect_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.disconnect_button.setEnabled(False)
        #make = self.device_make.placeholderText.connect(self.get_selected_items)
        
        
        self.show()

 

    def find_devices(self, devs):
        
        count = 0
        try: 
               
            if len(devs) == 0:
                print(" --- No Devices Found --- \n")   
            elif len(devs) > 0:
                for d in devs:
                    self.device_listbox.addItem(devs[count])
                    count += 1
            self.connect_button.setEnabled(True)                                           
        except:
            print("\nCould Not Find Devices\n")


    def get_selected_items(self):
        serial =  self.device_listbox.currentText()   
        print(serial)
        return serial
        
    # CONNECT TO SELECTED DEVICE (SERIAL)
    def connect_to_device(self):
        _serial = self.device_listbox.currentText()
        self.find_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.connect_button.setEnabled(False)
        num_devices = self.device_listbox.count()
        

        if num_devices == 1:
            try:
                twt()          
            except:
                print("\nCould Not Connect To Device\n")
        if num_devices > 1:
            try:
                self.find_button.setEnabled(False)
                self.connect_button.setEnabled(False)
                twt_ws(serial=_serial)
            except:
                print(f'Failed to connect to:{_serial}')
        elif num_devices == 0:
            print(f'\nNo Devices Found\n')
        
    def disconnect_from_device(self):
        self.device_listbox.setEnabled(True)
        self.find_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.connect_button.setEnabled(False)
        try:
            kill_server()
            print(f"Device Disconnect Successfully")
        except:
            print(f"Can't Disconnect From Device")

app = QApplication([])
window = TB_Main_Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

############################################################################################

```
from subprocess import Popen as send
import subprocess
import os



def twt(window_title='Twitedb3rn', width='480', height='900'):
    
    try:
        orientation()
        console_send = send(
            f"scrcpy --always-on-top --window-title={window_title} --window-width={width} --window-height={height} ",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True)
        _twt, errors = console_send.communicate()
        print(f'\n\tTWT Started\n\n!---START---!\n\n{_twt}\n!---END---!')
        console_send.wait()
    except:
        print(f'\nScrcpy Failed {errors}\n\n')
            

def twt_ws(window_title='Twitedb3rn', width='480', height='900', serial='99031FFBA0083T'):
        
        try:
            orientation_ws(serial)
            new_directoy = os.chdir('resources/scrcpy')
            console_send = send(
                f'scrcpy --always-on-top --window-title={window_title} --window-width={width} --window-height={height} -s{serial}',
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                text=True)
            _twt_ws, errors = console_send.communicate()
            console_send.wait()
            print(f'\n\tTWT Started\n\n!---START---!\n\n{_twt_ws}\n!---END---!')
        except:
            print(f'\nTWT Failed\n\n')
            print(errors)


#adb shell dumpsys window | grep 'mLandscapeRotation'
def orientation_ws(serial):
    try:
        console_send = send(
            f"adb -s {serial} shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True)
        _orientation, errors = console_send.communicate()
        console_send.wait()
        print(f'\nScreen Rotation Disabled')
        try:
            home = send(f'adb -s {serial} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME')
            home.communicate()
            home.wait()
            console_send = send(
            f"adb -s {serial} shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True)
            _orientation, errors = console_send.communicate()
            console_send.wait()
            print(f'\nScreen Set Landscape')
        except:
            print(f'\nScreen Landscape Failed')
            print(errors)
    except:
        print(f'\nScreen Rotation Not Disabled')
        print(errors)
    return errors

def orientation():
    try:
        console_send = send(
            f"adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True)
        _orientation, errors = console_send.communicate()
        console_send.wait()
        print(f'\nScreen Rotation Disabled')
        try:
            home = send(f'adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME')
            home.communicate()
            home.wait()
            console_send = send(
            f"adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True)
            _orientation, errors = console_send.communicate()
            console_send.wait()
            print(f'\nScreen Set Porttrait')
        except:
            print(f'\nScreen Portrait Failed')
            print(errors)
    except:
        print(f'\nScreen Portrait Not Disabled')
        print(errors)
    return errors
```

[image]

Comment: I should mention, the main py file that starts it all is inside the folder named '.TWT_BOT'

Comment: Well, yeah. `.communicate()` is blocking; the Qt event loop has no chance to run while it's waiting for that process to finish.

Comment: do I need to remove all .communicate() from my project then? Thank you very much

Comment: No - you will need to understand what you're doing with your subprocesses and use `communicate` etc. accordingly. (Many of those `Popen` (or "send") uses you have right now would be better served by `subprocess.check_call()`, by the way.)

Comment: wow thank you so much. I get it, I am not using it correctly and or as efficiently as it was meant to be. I am doing this project for my self and to learn as much as I can the right way as possible if that makes sense. So feedback and education like this is very very much appreciated. I now know I want to learn more about both the subprocess I have been running and maybe as well as multiple processes etc. Long thank you but I have been working on this for a couple of months from scratch and I haven't programmed since 2 -3 years ago when school was cancelled due to the world stopping. Thank you

Comment: by the way as soo as I removed the communicate from my twt func it did not freeze like you said. Thought everyone should know

Comment: Now that you've removed `communicate` and `wait`, you'll have the `scrcpy` subprocess hanging around until it quits on its own, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

All in all, it looks like your adb communication code is better formulated as something like the below.

Note I've elided all try/excepts; it's better to handle exceptions and errors "higher up" rather than just print out an error and let the program continue as if nothing bad had happened.

```
import subprocess


def set_adb_value(name, value):
    # TODO: this is not safe against shell injection vulnerabilities if `name` and `value`
    #       are user-controlled.
    subprocess.check_call(
        f"adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system "
        f"--bind name:s:{name} "
        f"--bind value:{value}"
    )


def set_orientation(landscape=False):
    # Disable screen rotation
    set_adb_value("accelerometer_rotation", "i:0")
    # Press home key
    subprocess.check_call("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME")
    # Set rotation
    set_adb_value("user_rotation", ("i:1" if landscape else "i:0"))


def start_scrcpy(window_title="Twitedb3rn", width="480", height="900", landscape=False):
    set_orientation(landscape=landscape)
    # TODO: this is not safe against shell injection vulnerabilities.
    return subprocess.Popen(
        f"scrcpy --always-on-top "
        f"--window-title={window_title} "
        f"--window-width={width} "
        f"--window-height={height}",
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to understand what you're doing with your subprocesses first, and then use `communicate` etc. accordingly.
Many of those `Popen` (or `send`) uses you have right now would be better served by `subprocess.check_call()`, by the way.

This was the answer.

I removed:

```py
_twt, errors = console_send.communicate()
console_send.wait()
```

and also:

```py
_twt_ws, errors = console_send.communicate()
console_send.wait()
```